# Is there a data dictionary view that allows one to monitor log usage by Process ID?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, logging

What (if any) data dictionary views on SQL Server 2005 allow one to monitor log space usage on active queries by Process ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of features in data dictionary. There are 3rd party tools which will read the transaction log real-time. Years ago I used a 3rd party tool, Log Explorer, to determine processes consuming log space. Looks like ApexLog does the same thing, but I haven't tried it.